# IIS Centralized Certificate Store not using certificate when loading in browser

Tags: iis, centralized-certificates

I have done the following:

- Installed the Centralized Certificate Store feature
- Created a network share and set the passwords
- Created `example.com.pfx` and `www.example.com.pfx` files in the share
- Verifed that my certificates are listed in IIS under `Centralized Certificates`
- Selected `Require Server Naem Indication` and `Use Centralized Certificate store` for my domain and created a site binding for the correct IP address and hostname `example.com`
- Stopped all websites except the one I'm working on.

My browser does not pick up the certificate!

It picks up the machine certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that `Require Server Name Indication` is enabled for ALL https site bindings on all sites. You have to globally use SNI or the centralized store gets confused.

It doesn't matter:

- If they are in websites that are disabled
- If they are NOT using the centralized store themselves.
- If they are using the machine certificate or another one

[image]

---

### TIP: I think I finally figured out WHY this is happening to me.

If you like to hit `Tab, Space, Tab, Space` to select checkboxes you need to SLOW DOWN. There's a strange bug somewhere and if you do `Tab, Space, Tab` too quickly it won't actually select the checkbox. So I think I was just zooming through many site bindings and some of them got skipped.