# Central Certificate Store Failures and Logging

Tags: windows-server-2019, iis-10, centralized-certificates

I've got IIS 10 on a Server 2019 instance with a Centralized Certificate Store configured.

The CCS looks valid in IIS. Certs are loaded and display no warnings or errors, but requests to any site returns a TCP reset.

- If I manually install the cert from the CCS into IIS it works too, so it's not a cert problem.
- I've verified with Wireshark that the Client Hello is including the the correct SNI host name that matches the file name in my CCS.
- Per [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/846819/iis-centralized-certificate-store-not-using-certificate-when-loading-in-browser), I've checked that Require SNI is enabled on all https bindings on the entire server (there are only two and both on the same site)
- The output of `netsh http show sslcert` looks like this: [image: Central Cert Store netsh output]

How can I debug this further? Is there some cert store log where I can get more details on failed requests (inetpub and httperr don't include them)?

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the failures by restarting the system... who knew!?

Never could find a log file of any kind...