IIS randomly stops serving HTTPS traffic
Have not found much information on this issue, so hoping someone has some light to shed. Server 2022 with IIS configured to use CCS, approx. 25 websites, either all or random ones will go down with a "connection reset" error when using HTTPS.
Sometimes a reboot of the server will fix it, other times a reboot yields no changes. Sometimes it is simple as going to a random website, unchecking use CCS, rechecking it and pressing "Apply" on a random site's HTTPS binding.
I have verified the CCS settings in IIS, verified permissions, all the certificate pfx names are valid and correct, it just randomly blows up.
netsh http show sslcert shows...
Central Certificate Store    : 443
Certificate Hash             : (null)
Application ID               : {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}
Certificate Store Name       : (null)
Verify Client Certificate Revocation : Enabled
Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only : Disabled
Usage Check                  : Enabled
Revocation Freshness Time    : 0
URL Retrieval Timeout        : 0
Ctl Identifier               : (null)
Ctl Store Name               : (null)
DS Mapper Usage              : Disabled
Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled
Reject Connections           : Disabled
Disable HTTP2                : Not Set
Disable QUIC                 : Not Set
Disable TLS1.2               : Not Set
Disable TLS1.3               : Not Set
Disable OCSP Stapling        : Not Set
Enable Token Binding         : Not Set
Log Extended Events          : Not Set
Disable Legacy TLS Versions  : Not Set
Enable Session Ticket        : Not Set
Extended Properties:
   PropertyId                   : 0
   Receive Window               : 1048576
   Extended Properties:
PropertyId                   : 1
   Max Settings Per Frame       : 2796202
   Max Settings Per Minute      : 4294967295
Extended Properties:
   PropertyId                   : 2
Extended Properties:
   PropertyId                   : 3
Extended Properties:
   PropertyId                   : 4


Actually you question seems to be the same as this one: https://serverfault.com/questions/1098876/central-certificate-store-failures-and-logging   (which is without an answer too).   You might need to find some more logging
